# Codeigniter routing with encoded params

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have the following route rule set in my config/routes.php:

`$route["add/url/(:any)"] = "add/url/$1/$2/$3";`

This works fine unless the params have encoded values so the following works:

`http://site.com/add/url/true/www.google.co.uk/Google/`

but this does not:

`http://site.com/add/url/true/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk/Google/`

It doesn't event seem to get to the controller function the page just says 'Object not found!'. What should I be doing?

Comment: The problem was down to the encoded /. In the end I decided to base64 the params and decode in the controller method.

Comment: Another way would be to pass the values through as a query string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions that I found:

1. base64 the params and decode in the controller method (making sure +,=,/ are substituted)
2. pass the values through as a query string

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$route["add/url/[A-Za-z0-9/%]"] = "add/url/$1/$2/$3";
```

or

```
$route["add/url/([\w][%])"] = "add/url/$1/$2/$3";
```

I am not quite sure for the second one but the first code works.

Please go through the article [Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regex) in Wikipedia for further more information on regular expression.

Comment: unfortunately neither worked and I was unable to find a regex solution